# firebase notification can not show in notification bar

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on the app and programmatically hide the app icon from the application drawer. I am using firebase notification for that and when I tap on the notification it gives this error.

```
W/FirebaseMessaging: No activity found to launch app
```

What should I do?

In my manifest file launcher set on mainActivity and the app icon hidden code is also in main activity.

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The mainactivity.java

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PackageManager p = this.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this,MainActivity.class);
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

secondActivity.java as below...

```
   private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
private TextView txtMessage,txtRegId;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    txtMessage= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    txtRegId= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.regId);

    mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // checking for type intent filter
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                // gcm successfully registered
                // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

                displayFirebaseRegId();

            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // new push notification is received

                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                txtMessage.setText(message);
            }
        }
    };

    displayFirebaseRegId();
}

private void displayFirebaseRegId() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
    String regId = pref.getString("regId", null);

    Log.e(TAG, "Firebase reg id: " + regId);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId))
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Firebase Reg Id: "+ regId, 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id: " + regId);
    else
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Firebase Reg Id is not received yet!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id is not received yet!");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // register GCM registration complete receiver
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));

    // register new push message receiver
    // by doing this, the activity will be notified each time a new message arrives
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));

    // clear the notification area when the app is opened
    NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java...

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        // play notification sound
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
    }else{
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
    }
}

private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
        String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
        JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
        Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
        Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
        Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            // check for image attachment
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text only
 */
private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text and image
 */
private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
}
```

I want to redirect to the secondActivity, when I tap op notification... help me..

Thanks in advance....

Comment: show us your FirebaseMessagingService class?

Comment: see my recent edited question please..

Comment: get any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer of my solution. Declare the broadcast receiver to check if the notification is coming and it will re enable the setting and then my app is now open when i tap on the notification.

```
 ComponentName componentToEnable = new ComponentName(context, MainActivity.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentToEnable, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Thank you all of you....

Answer (score 2):

If your application is in the foreground then you have to manage programmatically to display a notification in the notification bar, but if your app is in the background then firebase automatically handle it.

Answer (score 0):

declare your service class in manifest

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

update:

**Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background.** In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.

**Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and foreground.** In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

For More information Check this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: i have already did it.. but my application can not launch so i couldn't use that services..

Comment: no you should use this service. and your application not launching afterward than its different problem.. try to check your log.

Comment: sir as per define in my question.. i did the code at mainActivity.java to hide my app... and in menifest file i have to launch the main activity but it could't be opened or app is not launching... so what should i do.. my log file gives me firebase error which is not found any activity because of app not launched yet...

Comment: its says no activity found for launch app, so make sure you have declare your second activity in manifest

Comment: yup i declared it in menifest but launch code is under main activity... so how can i open the second activity /?

Comment: and if i am not goint to write code for hide appicon in the mainactivity it will not be hidden.... so i have to write it in there thats the main problem... both opposite natured task is performing in one activity... suggest me if there is any alternamte way...